# Python 3 - Hollow Rectangle

Tags: python-3.x

I have an assignment, where we have to write a module to create certain hollow shapes and use them later on in the assignment. I'm having a slight issue with the alignment of the last column in the rectangle.

My code is this:

```
height = eval(input("Enter the height:\n"))

width = eval(input("Enter the width:\n"))

gap=" "

def print_rectangle(height, width):
    for i in range(height):
        if i == 0 or i == height-1:
            print(width*'*')
        else: 
            print('*' + gap*width +'*')   


print_rectangle(height,width)
```

Which prints:

```
****** 
*      *
*      *
*      *
*      *
*      *
*      *
*      *
******
```

any hint which would line it up correctly like this would be appreciated:):

```
******
*    *
*    *
*    *
*    *
*    *
*    *
*    *
******
```

Comment: You need to do `print('*' + gap*(width-2) + '*')`. You forgot to account for the asterisks, so you have a couple extra spaces.

Comment: You print the gap a number of times equal to the total width. Your actual gap should be 2 spaces smaller...  Also, eval is a bad idea; use `int()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print('*' + gap*width +'*')
```

This will print a line of size `width+2`. `width` spaces, and two stars.
If you want the line to be size `width`, then print two fewer spaces.

```
print('*' + gap*(width-2) +'*')
```

Comment: ah, thank you! I had done something similar except I put the bracket around the entire thing so it read:

    print('*' + (gap*width-2) +'*')

which provided an error, thanks for pointing out my mistake:)