# python rectangle of asterisks?

Tags: python

I am new to programming and I have an assignment that needs me to build a rectangle of "stars" that has a row of 6 then below it, a row of 5, then another row of 6 and so on and so on. I need to use a nested loop but cant seem to get past the first line.
Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    # Setup accumulator and variable

    rows = 0
    stars = 0

    # Get user inputs
    rows = int(input("How many rows for this design?\n"))
    stars = int(input("How many stars on the first row?\n"))

    # Print i
    for i in range(stars):
        print("*", end="")
        break
```

2nd try:

def main():

```
# Get user inputs
rows = int(input("How many rows for this design?\n"))
stars = int(input("How many stars on the first row?\n"))

# Print i
for i in range(stars):
    for j in range(rows):
        print(stars*"*")        
        print(rows*"*")
        break
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845796/python-3-hollow-rectangle

Comment: Could you give an example of the output you'd expect for a given input or rows and stars? It's not clear to me what you mean by "rectangle of asterisks" when you also say "a row of 6 then below it, a row of 5, then another row of 6 and so on".

Comment: It should be atlernating rows: a row for the input "6" then a row below it with "5" asterisks repeating 9 times:def main():
    
    # Get user inputs
    rows = int(input("How many rows for this design?\n"))
    stars = int(input("How many stars on the first row?\n"))

    # Print i
    for i in range(stars):
        for j in range(rows):
            print(stars*"*")        
            print(rows*"*")
            break

Comment: wont let me put in my new example...

Comment: you need to add an example of what your output should look like

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can use `modulo` and `stars-1` to alternate the output:

```
rows = int(input("How many rows for this design?\n"))
stars = int(input("How many stars on the first row?\n"))

for i in range(rows):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(stars * "*")
    else:
        print ((stars-1) * "*")
```

For 9 rows and 6 stars it outputs:

```
******
*****
******
*****
******
*****
******
*****
******
```

`if i % 2 == 0:` will output 6 stars for each even `i` else  we will print `stars-1` stars.

Using a nested for loop:

```
for i in range(rows):
    s = ""
    for j in range(stars):
        s += "*"
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(s)
    else:
        print(s[:-1])
```

Comment: One more question: is this considered using a "nested" loop?

Comment: @corvette1, no, we only have one loop.

Comment: ok then, I understand if statements and it does work correctly that way, but it needs to have a "nested loop" to create that output. How do I do that?

Comment: @corvette1 : You make an outer `for` loop that controls the number of rows and inside that you make an other `for` loop that creates and prints a single row, star by star. However, doing that in this case is rather un-Pythonic because we can easily make a row with `stars * "*"`, but I guess it's ok as a learning exercise. If you need help with this new version, it might be a good idea to post your new code in a new question. (Is that right Padraic?)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound much like a rectangle to me, but the way I would do this is to use a conditional expression that selects the length of each row according to the remainder when the row number is divided by two.

It would look like this

```
rows  = int(input("Number of rows for this design: "))
stars = int(input("Number of stars on the first row: "))

for row in range(rows):
    len = stars if row % 2 == 0 else stars - 1
    print '*' * len
```

**output**

```
Number of rows for this design: 9
Number of stars on the first row: 6
******
*****
******
*****
******
*****
******
*****
******
```

Comment: Perhaps `len = stars if row % 2 == 0 else stars - 1` is a bit too hi-tech at this stage of corvette1's learning curve. But I guess it's a __lot__ less cryptic than `x=6;y=9;row=x*'*';print('\n'.join([row[:x-i%2] for i in xrange(y)]))` :)

Comment: Yep, First time programming. Thank you though.